# Writing norm2 of a column vector

Tags: equations, labels, subequations, vector

I am writing my first Latex document and I am having some struggles. I need to write a cost function as the norm2 of a column vector and I would like to have a numbered equation label. So far I have tried something like

```
\begin{subequations}
\label{eqn:aaa}
  \begin{align*}[left = {J_{LSQ} = \left\|}, right = \right\|_2]
    & \frac{1}{\tau_n}(T_{num} - T(k^{right},L_0^{right},L_t^{right},k^{left},L_0^{left},L_t^{left})\\
    & \frac{1}{\delta_n}(\Delta_{num} - \delta(L_t^{right},\Gamma_{right})\\
    & \frac{1}{\delta_n}(\Delta_{num} - \delta(L_t^{left},\Gamma_{left})\\
   \end{align*}
\end{subequations}
```

\autoref{eqn:aaa}

where I use align* to avoid printing labels for every subequations. However by doing so I can reference the Equation, but it's not printing the label on his side.
[image: I obtain this, and I want (7.2) to be written on the side of the equation.]

I obtain this, and I want (7.2) to be written on the side of the equation.

Comment: You can use \notag with align, or `\left\|\begin{array}{l} ... \end{array}\right\|`

Comment: Where does this syntax come from: `  \begin{align*}[left = {J_{LSQ} = \left\|}, right = \right\|_2]` ??

Comment: For the content of the equation, you could use simply: `\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:aaa} %\tag{2.7}
J_{LSQ} = \begin{Vmatrix*}[l]
   \frac{1}{\tau_n}(T_{num} - T(k^{right},L_0^{right},L_t^{right},k^{left},L_0^{left},L_t^{left})
   \\[4pt]
   \frac{1}{\delta_n}(\Delta_{num} - \delta(L_t^{right},\Gamma_{right})
   \\[4pt]
   \frac{1}{\delta_n}(\Delta_{num} - \delta(L_t^{left},\Gamma_{left})
\end{Vmatrix*}_{2}
\end{equation}`

Comment: My previous comment had two completely separate approached, with the latter not using align at all.